# Split Letters Into Combination Chunks w/ Simplified Query

Tags: php, mysql, string, math

It's a confusion problem - so the wording may seem hard to follow. I'm likely over complicating a simple problem. Added an example question to help figure this out.

### Example Question

Finding a 5 letter word from a database with the characters hxinenvarbav. I've organized the words in the DB to also contain a column of the word in alphabetical format. This means, the word "happy" has a column with the value "ahppy", so from the letters hxinenvarbav I can alphabetically organize them using the following code.

```
<?
    $letters = str_split('hxinenvarbav'); asort($letters);
    $letters = implode('',$letters); // returns 'aabehinnrvvx'
?>
```

### The Issue

However, I can't simply search with mysql "LIKE '%aabehinnrvvx%' " and find 5 letter words with those characters, as obviously that will not pull any results. Unless maybe there is a MySQL query I could do? Maybe organize the column differently. I can however, use str_split($letters,5) to take 5 letters chunks of the 12 letter combination.

How would I go about, splitting in chunks each possible 5 letter combination from these 12 letters while keeping in mind, I need to query the table.

Does this make sense? Do I need to elaborate any further? Likely, I'm just over thinking and can't seem to simplify what it is I'm trying to accomplish. I have some complex mathematics that can find all possible combinations. But since I have placed in alphabetical order, I'm only searching combinations - not permutations. And on top of that, I don't *need* to as far as I logically believe, query 'each' combination. As there are 792 possible 5 letter combinations from only 12 letters (without calculating repeating characters). So 792 query calls is not nice - and 792 OR statements in my query, is clearly not an option. LOL!.

Any suggestions?

I did just think about searching via available characters left from alphabet - but, some words have repeating letters so that's not an option either.

Comment: Have you looked into regex?

Comment: A regex would need to be formatted to search for 5 letter chunks. I can't fathom a way to do an expression that separates 12 letters into 5 letter chunks in one query. Is that possible?

Comment: The only other option might be to index the letter counts for each word.   Fastest search for ASCII encoding may be 26 int fields.

Comment: LOL, be careful when suggesting that any option might be the "only" other option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table named "dict" that contains fields "word", and "combo", where "combo" contains the alphabetized characters of each "word", then you can index on "combo".

You programmatically build your set of combinations in memory, and use it to build a SELECT statement based on each combination using IN clause, like "SELECT * FROM dict WHERE combo IN ('combo1', 'combo2', ..., 'comboN');".

Should be pretty fast and simple to implement.

Comment: But if someone is searching 6 letter combinations from a 12 letter possible, that's a query with 924 combo's - seems lengthy to me. Especially if I expand to a 26 letter combination possibility in the future. Could turn into a query with 1 million plus combinations. No longer a fast and simple query

Comment: I just mean at most 26 OR statements.  Its ugly but would be faster than a join or regex

Comment: Ugly - but it would work. I'll work on this for a bit. If I find a better solution, I'll let you know @user1389596 .. I'll work with that for now and see what I can work out this evening. Thanks dude.

Comment: @JamesCordeiro if your SQL statement exceeds some sort of limit, be it number of characters in the statement itself, or number of elements in an IN clause, you can still break it into multiple statements.

Comment: @user1389596 I'm intrigued that both of you see an optimization, but I'm not fully understanding your solution.  If 12 characters are given and all valid 6-character words are desired, then what would your query look like?

Comment: @phatfingers I thought it was only looking for words that contained combinations of those letters.  Like: `select * from words where wordlength = 6 and ( a > 1 h > 1 or p > 1 or y > 1 )`.  Or it might AND the letters.   Anything that's trying to actually compute this space of possibilities can be expensive, since the possibilities grow very quickly.

Comment: So, if the full set of characters was "HAPPYCOUPLES", and you wanted all combinations that mapped to 6-letter words, what would prevent a word like "HOPING" from being matched?

Comment: @user1389596 - after evaluation, you're correct - it will not work the way that "phatfingers" had presented. Take the following as an example:

hxinenvarbav in alphabetical is aabehinnrvvx
I will not find all possible words from that solution because the word would need to be in the alphabetical combination aabehinnrvvx. I would have to evaluate all 720 possibilities.

I'm sorry "phatfingers" - the query will not work - at least not fully.

Comment: @phatfingers Good point, in that case it would also need something like `and ( i = 0 and n = 0 and g = 0 and ... )`. The second part would contain the compliment of OR search chars. So it always total 26 fields in the search, plus a length. The filter you want would be OR'ed, the filter you don't want would be AND'ed.

Comment: Oops I added an answer not a comment... getting late :)

Comment: @JamesCordeiro, you said you had some complex mathematics that could provide you with a list of all desired combinations.  Storing an indexed combination for each word in the database would avoid having to calculate all permutations.  Assuming the characters of both your calculated combination and the stored combination are organized in alphabetical sequence, why would the query not work?

Comment: @user1389596 thanks for the clarification.  I like your approach and believe it would work, too.  You should put it into a separate answer so James can credit you for it.  A clause like "WHERE a<=? AND b<=? AND c<=? ... z<=?" would do the job for any sized word without having to compute any combinations.

Comment: @phatfingers I like your optimization of the query.  That looks a lot cleaner and helps mysql with indexing too, since the query fields are always in a fixed order.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not to accomplish this with only one SQL statement, but a combination of SQL and post query filtering for performance reasons.

```
select * from A where word_len = 5 and (
 substring( word_in_db, 1, 1) IN ('h', 'x', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'v')
 and 
 substring( word_in_db, 2, 1) IN ('h', 'x', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 
-- etc...
)
```

This will limit the amount of clauses to the amount of letters in your target word.

This won't find duplicates like a word that has 2 Es but input letters with only 1 E.  You will probably want to compute the word length and save that as a derived value for speed (and index the column, of course).

Comment: You might want to sort the letters in the DB not in alphabetical order, but in order of their commonality, putting letters like z and q at the beginning and vowels and common letters (like "r,s,t,l,n,e") at the end.  This will short circuit the where clause as soon as possible and save many many substr calls.